# Cassandra bookmark table data modeling

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I want to model table with the following functionalities -

1. I can fetch the bookmarked items in descending timestamp order
2. I can delete individual bookmarked item.

My table looks like this-

```
CREATE TABLE bookmarked_content(
user_id uuid,
type varchar,
timestamp timestamp,
item_id uuid,
primary key(user_id, type, timestamp)
WITH CLUSTERING KEY (type , timestamp DESC)
);
```

Now this is fine for fetching all the bookmarked of specific type in descending timestamp order, But the problem is I can't delete specific item from the table and I don't want to depend on secondary indexes for this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you expect `rename()` to change the permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing to do except using plain old [`chmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) function:

```
rename($from, $to);
chmod($to, $mode);
```